# dragging and dropping from one JavaFX Application to another

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx-8

I am trying to move an element from one JavaFX application to another via drag-and-drop, as far as I understand this shouldnt be a problem.

So I have an object of a class and drag it from one application to the other and then have its contents printed to the console. It's mostly looking good, I can get the drop to "accepted" or "not accepted" by playing around with transfer modes, which shows me that the mechanism itself seems to be working.
But when I drop the object on the other application a bunch of, what I believe to be mostly chinese, letters are printed to the console. This is apparently some encoding problem, but I can't really figure out what's happening, aside from the fact that both applications mainly use the same codebase, the "chinese" letters are quite numerous. The object's toString merely prints one and a half line in latin characters, but upon dropping there are several paragraphs of "chinese" letters printed.

Can anyone tell me what's happening here? Is it just a simple encoding f-up? Does the OS (Win7 btw) maybe interfer here? Have I uncovered long lost ancient chinese wisdom?

The code itself is rather simple, here is the code from the "sender"

```
setOnDragDetected(event ->
            {
                Dragboard db = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
                clipboardContent.put(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT, treeElement.getEntities());

                db.setContent(clipboardContent);

                System.out.println(db.getContent(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT));

                event.consume();
            });
```

and here from the "receiver"

```
setOnDragDropped(event ->
    {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        if (db.hasContent(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT))
        {
            System.out.println(db.getContent(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT));
            System.out.println("Accept Drop");
        }

        event.consume();
    });
```

I just don't really see anything that would explain my error.

Comment: What kind of object does `treeElement.getEntities()` return? Is there any specific reason you're using reference type `Boolean` instead of primitive type `boolean` in the second code snippet?

Comment: It returns List<Entity>, Entity implements serializeable and is part of the already-mentioned common codebase of both applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is using `DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT`. This means JavaFX considers the data format to be just what it says on the tin: text, i.e. `String` data. This is not really the case. There is no `static` member of `DataFormat` that refers to a suitable `DataFormat`, so you need to create one on your own:

```
final String mimeType = "application/javafx-entrylist"; // TODO: choose properly

// use existing format or introduce new one
DataFormat f = DataFormat.lookupMimeType(mimeType);
final DataFormat format = f == null ? new DataFormat(mimeType) : f;

setOnDragDetected(event -> {
    Dragboard db = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

    ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
    clipboardContent.put(format, treeElement.getEntities());

    db.setContent(clipboardContent);

    System.out.println(db.getContent(format));

    event.consume();
});

setOnDragDropped(event -> {
    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    if (db.hasContent(format)) {
        System.out.println(db.getContent(format));
        System.out.println("Accept Drop");
    }

    event.consume();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I already figured it was a problem with the DataFormat when various translators failed to translate the chinese ;)